# Log4j configuration - Only stdout log are ok

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have this log4j configuration file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!--  Log4j Configuration                                                  -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->

<!-- $Id: jboss-log4j.xml 75507 2008-07-08 20:15:07Z stan.silvert@jboss.com $ -->

<!--
   | For more configuration infromation and examples see the Jakarta Log4j
   | owebsite: http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j
 -->

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

   <!-- ================================= -->
   <!-- Preserve messages in a local file -->
   <!-- ================================= -->

   <!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
   <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="false"/>

      <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

      <!-- Rollover at the top of each hour
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
      -->

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>

         <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
          -->
      </layout>
   </appender>

 

   <!-- ============================== -->
   <!-- Append messages to the console -->
   <!-- ============================== -->

   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>       
   
   <!-- ================ -->
   <!-- Limit categories -->
   <!-- ================ -->

   <!-- Limit the org.apache category to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.apache">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the jacorb category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
   <category name="jacorb">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>
   
   <!-- Limit the org.jgroups category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
   <category name="org.jgroups">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>
   
   <!-- Limit the org.quartz category to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.quartz">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit JSF logging to DEBUG.  FINER and FINEST will not be logged -->
   <category name="javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf">
      <priority value="INFO" />
   </category>
                
   <!-- Limit JBoss categories  -->
   <category name="org.jboss">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>
   

   <!-- Limit the JSR77 categories -->
   <category name="org.jboss.management">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>
    
   <category name="org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.BasicLazyInitializer">
    <priority value="FATAL"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException">
    <priority value="FATAL"/>
   </category>

   
   
   <!-- Limit the org.jboss.serial (jboss-serialization) to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.jboss.serial">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>      

  
   <!-- ======================= -->
   <!-- Setup the Root category -->
   <!-- ======================= -->

   <root>
      <priority value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
   </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

In my java class I have :

```
protected org.apache.log4j.Logger logger =org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```

And I log with :

logger.info("something   " + something);

But either in logger.info or logger.debug, I have nothing in my server.log file.

The server.log file contains only external lib log or stdout and stderr log of my application (com.myapp packages). I don't have any info or debug log of my application. It seems that I have to use console log (System.out.println), why ?

Thank you